# C# JSON - Serializing Objects depending on conditions

Tags: c#, json

I have on list of strings that represent my selected users.

I want to serialize a JSON in which one of the properties is Selected. it is true if the user is in the List and false if he is not.

right now i have this:

```
ViewBag.Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Utilizadores = db.Utilizador.Select(u => new { Id = u.Id, Nome = u.Nome, Info = u.NumMecanografico, Selected = false })
            });
```

Example Final Result:

I want something like this, imagina User 1 and 2 are in the list. and I have 4 users total.

```
Utilizadores = [Id:1, Nome: User1, Selected: true],[Id:2, Nome: User2, Selected: true],[Id:3, Nome: User3, Selected: false],[Id:4, Nome: User4, Selected: false]
```

Something like this.

Right now I don't see how I can do the condition here. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Can you show Utilizador class? I think there's quite a bit confusion

Comment: It doesn't have any selected attribute if that's what you want to know. The selected is just for the JSON.

Comment: What misses here is your condition for what makes a user selected or not. Where does this information comes from? Request parameters? A boolean stored in the database?

Comment: @Crono see my answer. I think OP assumes there is a list, collection or whatever somewhere. Anyway, surely there not enough code for a complete answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpreted your question in the means that "you have a `List` of selected users, so the JSON property `Selected` is true **if the user is in the list**"

```
IList<string> selectedUsers = ... //The list of selected usernames
ViewBag.Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Utilizadores = db.Utilizador.Select(u => new { Id = u.Id, Nome = u.Nome, Info = u.NumMecanografico, Selected = selectedUsers.Contains(u.Nome) })
            });
```

Comment: It kinda works.I put true instead of false in the end cause thats what I want. But how do I set the other that arent in the list as false?

Comment: Sorry I think I completely misanswered. Just fixed the code

Comment: I came to an answer myself but I think mine was a bit more complex than this one. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add a **Where** selector.

```
ViewBag.Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
     Utilizadores = db.Utilizador.Where(u => u.Selected).Select(u => u...)
});
```